Feasible / easy to mount a Frame TV on this wood overlay on brick fireplace?
First time posting here & admittedly not the most handy. My wife is a big fan of the Frame TVs and we're looking into putting one over our fireplace. We don't intend to ever use the fireplace, but the question is - does it seem feasible/"easy" enough to mount a Frame TV on this wood overlay above our fireplace with brick behind it?



It is always good to use a tv to watch a fireplace burning above a fireplace.

Putting a TV above a fireplace is never recommended. The angle is too high for comfortable viewing, and if you actually use the fireplace the heat and smoke will shorten the life of the set. But people insist on doing it anyway, since it looks good in magazine photos of rooms people don't actually live in...

@keshlam, I disagree.  The TV is not too high.  In my opinion many people have it too low, which causes neck pain.  It also does to get that hot above most fireplaces, otherwise the timber above would be singing.  My comments are based on my own usage in several houses.  Many fireplaces such as this one have a wood mantelpiece that sticks out and it does not singe either.   IN one of our house, the local authority insisted on us mounting a heat deflector kit under the mantlepiece.  In practice it turned out to be a pointless waste of money.

We agree that we disagree. I invite you to consider which seats you find most comfortable in a movie theater. Most of us refer not to have eye level below the bottom of the screen. Many prefer to have eye level even with the middle of the screen,  or even above that. A reclining seat _may_correct the sight line enough to be ergonomically comfortable, but will  leave keystoning unresolved unless the screen is tilted downward to compensate.

What is a "frame TV"?

Frame is a Samsung model line.

You can mount a TV there but must understand how the wall above the fireplace is constructed.   It might be all brick, or the brick flue might be set back with a stud wall in front of it, from the top of the mantle to the ceiling.   In either case, the wood facing might be fastened to the wall securely or poorly and it might be made of thin weak material or solid wood.
If it's a solid wood facing at least half an inch thick and securely mounted to the wall, you can attach your TV bracket to it.
If the wood facing isn't suitable, you need to drill through it and attach the bracket to the wall behind it.   And to do that you MUST know how that wall is built.  If it's a stud wall you have to find the studs, and that will be difficult with the wood facing but you have to do it.  Since you'll have a TV there you can afford to make some ugly experimental holes to determine what's behind it.
In the end:

Wood screws into a strong, securely fastened wood facing
Wood screws into studs behind the facing
Masonry wall anchors and screws into brick behind the facing

... as required.

There are two parts to the problem.

Will the timber support the TV?  You could hammer in a couple of nails and suspend a weight from them, that is 2 to 3 times the weight of the TV, to test.
Will the temperature get too high for the TV?  Obtain a thermometer and track the temperature above the wood mantle, when the fire is on and is burning fiercely.

